# Parse JSON into class without JsonProperty

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization

Example data:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "01234": {
      "001": "20",
      "123": "10"
    },
    "56789": {
      "001": "100",
      "328": "5"
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to check to make sure the "status" = "success" and if so, then flatten the "data" into more of a relational structure to store in a relational database.  From the above it would look something like:

```
Product Location  Quantity
01234   001       20
01234   123       10
56789   001       100
56789   328       5
```

My understanding is since the "01234" and "56789" are going to change I'm not going to be able to create a class to deserialize into using a JsonProperty.

How do I go about deserializing this into a class?  Would it be easier to just deserialize without using a class?

**Edit**

I was able to get it to work based on the accepted answer, but am wondering why this doesn't work (it's what I was trying before posting this question):

```
public class FindResponse { 
    [JsonProperty("status")] 
    public string status { get; set; } 
    [JsonProperty("data")] 
    public FindResponseData data { get; set; } 
} 

public class FindResponseData { 
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> sku { get; set; } 
} 

//This doesn't work; the "data" in the "result" object was null. 
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FindResponse>(skusJson);
```

Comment: It's because the **data** property is not of Dictionary type rather it's of type **FindResponseData** which in turn having a Dictionary property with name **sku**. So when Serializer tries to map the **data** property from the json, it will look for a value which should be an object with a property **sku** which can be further mapped as dictionary. In that case, the json should be something like {   "status": "success",   "data": {"sku":{    "01234": {       "001": "20",       "123": "10"     },     "56789": {       "001": "100",       "328": "5"     }   } }}.

Comment: @SivaramK Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a class as below and try to map the data using the dictionary values after [deserialization](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDictionary.htm). May not be the better approach but it will suit your data model.

```
public class MyClass {
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> Data { get; set; }
    }

   //and then
   var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(jsonContent);
```

Comment: It would be more convenient using **Hashtable** instead of Dictionaries.

Comment: @sivaram-k thanks.  That worked.  I updated the question to include what I was initially trying, which wasn't working.